# Why was Mordechai wearing royal clothing a second time?

Tags: clothing, megillat-esther, mordechai

In Esther 8:15 Mordechai goes out wearing royal clothing again. This seems to be a singular reward; what precipitated this?

Comment: wouldn't it just be because he was mishne lamelech?

Answer (score 0):

possible...

it is the same set of royal clothing in both psukimm
in between these two periods, mordechai put back on the sackcloth (talmud:megilla) due to the jews being under threat

only when the threat was removed did he remove the sackcloth and wear only the t try oy all set (manos halevi,gri”z)

Answer (score -1):

[this](https://youtu.be/VigpBnX7kOk) (start from 46:50), based on the meam loez,  says that he also had Tzittzit and tefillin so that every one would know that,  The One in Power now is a jew.